# Playing / Embedding Flash Videos In HTML

Tags: html, actionscript-3, flash, video

I have a website that shows flash videos (Provided to me in `.flv` format) but I cannot work out how to get them to play.  I've looked at various tutorials / code snippets but none work as I assume that they are missing something.

Here is the (updated) code that I have:

```
    <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" width="400" height="300" id="movie" align="center">
   <embed src="cms/videos/<?php echo $type; ?>/<?php echo $id; ?>.flv" quality="high" width="400" height="300" name="movie" align="center" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" plug inspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
   <param name="movie" value="cms/videos/<?php echo $type; ?>/<?php echo $id; ?>.flv" /> 
</object>
```

How can I get this to work?  Do I need an `swf` file and if so where do I get it from.  Is there a resourse that shows a fully working (up to date) script?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting what you do with `.swf` and `.flv` in single so I explain it by example.

Here is a generalized version of the standard method of including Flash content in web pages. Embed Flash via object and embed.

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" width="400" height="300" id="movie" align="center">
   <embed src="movie.swf" quality="high" width="400" height="300" name="movie" align="center" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" plug inspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
   <param name="movie" value="movie.swf" /> 
</object>
```

You ca read more about this [here](https://perishablepress.com/embed-flash-and-video-via-the-object-tag/).

Comment: Thanks.  My clients videos are in `.FLV` format so I need them to be played as that format.

Comment: Is there a way of making this work to play `.flv` files?

Comment: I suggest one other option: http://www.joellipman.com/articles/web-development/392-embed-an-flv-file-into-a-web-page.html

Comment: This is step by step embed an FLV file into a web page.

Comment: Thanks, I can see that this would be a good way of embedding and that it would work well, however I found another online script that does the trick.  Thanks again.